# Select multiple images without Image-Picker plugin ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am searching for an alternative to Ionic's image-picker plugin or some guidance on using it to attach a file to a Form for upload.  The api that I am using requires that file be uploaded via form. Thoughts or suggestions are much appreciated.  The feature of multiple file selection is the most important part of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use standard web api (file input) to achieve this and use "multiple" as attribute.

Your template:

```
<button ion-button>
     <ion-icon name="image"></ion-icon>
     <input multiple type="file” (change)="loadImageFromDevice($event)" accept="image/png, image/jpeg">
</button>
```

Your ts:

```
    myImages: Array<string>;

    ...

    loadImageFromDevice(event) {
        const files = event.target.files;
        const blobReader = new FileReader();
        files.forEach(file => {
            blobReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
            blobReader.onload = () => {
                let blob: Blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array((blobReader.result as ArrayBuffer))]);
                let blobURL: string = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                this.myImages.push(blobURL);
            };
            blobReader.onerror = (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            };
        })
      };
```

Comment: the usual problem: doesn't allow multiple selection on Android

Comment: do you see this issue also with latest Android devices? it seems like multiple is supported by Android but very spotty.

Comment: well i have 8.1 and multiple select never works on it no matter how i try :( but i saw at several other places that other people also have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same issue

use this code to choose file in Ionic HTML

---

```
  <ion-input type="file" (change)="changeListener($event)"></ion-input>
```

---

Ts file

---

```
changeListener(event) {
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
reader.onload = (_event) => {
  this.imgURL = reader.result;
  //base64 image
  console.log("Image File =>", this.imgURL);
}
```

}

---

Then make file controller array and make one button to increase it then you can make multiple file controls to handle and upload to server.

check this for reference
http://masteringionic.com/blog/2018-02-06-dynamically-add-and-remove-form-input-fields-with-ionic/